# Using relations in parse

Tags: android

Can someone please help me out on how to use relationships in parse for android. I building an app where users can create groups and view posts pertaining to the particular group.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, you should create the relationship inside your table in Parse.com as a new column. The relationship have to be with an existent table, mandatory.

After that, you can only add to the relation objects previously created in your database, otherwise you shouldn't add them to the relation.

Now, you can create a new object, and then you have to retrieve the relation of your object. You can do it like this example. We create a new object **book**, and then we retrieve the relation **"authors"**. The authors we add to the relation are objects previously created and stored in our database.

`now we create a book object
ParseObject book = new ParseObject("Book");`

// now lets associate the authors with the book
// remember, we created a "authors" relation on Book
`ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = book.getRelation("authors");
relation.add(authorOne);
relation.add(authorTwo);
relation.add(authorThree);`

// now save the book object

`book.saveInBackground();`

Remember to always save the object to save the relationship.